# Showing `print` logs for SwiftUI apps without XCode

Tags: swift, macos, logging, swiftui, console

I have simple `SwiftUI.App` for MacOS where I use `print` for debug logs.
As far as I understand I should use `os_log` for regular "unified" logging, but can use `print` for my personal debug logs that will be excluded from releases of my app.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Main: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("Debug") {
                print("print")
                NSLog("NSLog")
                os_log("os_log")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this app I can see some logs in the *Console.app* on MacOS. It shows the entries for `NSLog` and `os_log` but not the `print` entry. The *Console.app* was the only place where I could see logs at all. Actually I want to see all logs on the command line, as I am used to from console applications (e.g., try `swift <(echo 'print("success")')`).

I start my app using `open MyApp.app` with the app binary located at `./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`. I also tried opening it with `open MyApp.app -W` to avoid it getting detached to the background and expecting some console output. However, there was none.

Which leads me to the following questions:

1. Where can I see the `print` output my `swift build -c debug` builds in general (without XCode)?
2. How can I make this `SwiftUI.App` log to the console when running from the command line?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104588/how-to-get-stdout-into-console-app) might be of interest.

Comment: Just run in Terminal `# ./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` and you'll see all output.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi `./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` works for now. I had seen errors when calling the binary without `open` before. But now it works. I would still be interested where the `print` logs can be seen if I start my app regularly (not from the command line).